# Get List Items using ECMAscript CAML query

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, client-object-model, caml-query

Hi can anyone show me how can I retieve list items based on 2 fields using ECMAscript CAML? I have a list where I have uid as number and city as text.

I want to retrieve all items where uid = 100 and city='A'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To return items from a list using ECMAScript (JavaScript, JScript), use the getItemById(id) function to return a single item, or use the getItems(query) function to return multiple items. You then use the load(clientObject) function to attain list item objects that represent the items.

Try the following:

```
var siteUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection';

function retrieveListItems() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Announcements');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'uid\'/><Value Type=\'Number\'>100</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'city\'/><Value Type=\'Text\'>A</Value></Eq</And></Where></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>');
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));        

}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

    var listItemInfo = '';

    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() + 
            '\nTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('Title') + 
            '\nBody: ' + oListItem.get_item('Body');
    }

    alert(listItemInfo.toString());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Reference: [How to: Retrieve List Items Using JavaScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185007%28v=office.14%29.aspx)